# How can i send data through an API to other servers only using Nodejs and Express?

Tags: javascript, html, express

I'm new to NodeJS and I am currently working on getting an API working. Currently running is Express for that purpose and i really would like to stick to express to solve it.

My goal is to let other people send me their data through links (Example would be: http://localhost:1000/api/?product=test) so i can just grab them with a simple 'var productname = req.param('product'); That part works just fine.

But i would like to simply call a method to send data from my server, meaning  i would like to trigger sending the data with a function and then send the data as a link to another server. (Example would be to http://google.com/search?q=test) 
I can't seem to get it to work even if i directly work with the documentation from express: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback

Could anyone point me in the right direction? 
If i try the code snippet below, I'm not even getting a console.log.

My current code attempt is:

```
 // testing purpose to call the method and get a console log 
sendServerUpdates('chair');
function sendServerUpdates(product){
        url = 'google.com/';  
        app.get(url + 'search', (res) => {
            const {statusCode} = res;
            const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

            let error;
            if (statusCode !== 200) {
                error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' + `Status Code: 
${statusCode}`);
            } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
                error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' + `Expected 
 application/json but received ${contentType}`);
            }
            if (error) {
                console.error(error.message);
                // Consume response data to free up memory
                res.resume();
                return;
            }
            // Information for me that the system is sending a message
            console.log('sending update');
            // sending (if its working) the parameter product
            res.status(200).send(product);
        })


    }

}
```

Comment: Give this a go: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request. It's a bit hard to decipher what you want here, but to me it seems you simply want to do a http GET to some api. I personally think Request with async/await is cool. Node has HTTP built in as well, if you like that better.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it! To stay true to the example above, i have a var with the name product which i want to send to another server via http. So if the value of var is 'chair' i want my computer to send the var like this: http://example.com/api?product=chair so the other server can just grab it from the link.

Comment: Depends on the external api of course. Maybe you need to make a post and not a queried get

Comment: The receiving API would consist of:
    app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
        productname = req.param('fuel');
                }
            }
        }
    });